# Why isn't my method call working from a different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a new programmer, and know the basics of IOS and Objective C Programming, but have run into a bug.

All I am trying to do is when a button is clicked, it calls a method from another class.

The Method I am trying to call is: [phoneCompany printPrompt];

So here is my code:

First Class: (ViewController)

.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
#import "PhoneCompany.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize dialTextField;
@synthesize dialButton;
@synthesize textFromCall;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.dialTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(83, 101, 154, 30)];
    self.dialTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.dialTextField.placeholder = @"Dial Number";
    self.dialTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.dialTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.dialTextField.minimumFontSize = 20;
    self.dialTextField.autocorrectionType = NO;
    self.dialTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.dialTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.dialTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.dialTextField];

    self.dialButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.dialButton setTitle:@"Dial!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.dialButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    [self.dialButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.dialButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.dialButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mainCall) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.dialButton.frame =CGRectMake(92, 400, 125, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:self.dialButton];

    self.textFromCall = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48,155,220,240)];
    [self.textFromCall setText:@"Hello, what number would you like to call?"];
    self.textFromCall.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.textFromCall.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    self.textFromCall.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self.textFromCall setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self.textFromCall setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.textFromCall setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview: self.textFromCall];
}


-(void) mainCall{

    if([self.dialTextField.text isEqualToString:@"1234567"]){

        self.dialButton.enabled = NO;
        self.dialTextField.enabled = NO;

        PhoneCompany *phoneCompany = [[PhoneCompany alloc]init];


        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target:phoneCompany selector:@selector(printPrompt)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        self.textFromCall.text = @"Dialing...";
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target:self selector:@selector(connectingStatement)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];



}

else if([self.dialTextField.text isEqualToString: nil]){
        self.textFromCall.text = @"Please enter a phone number.";
    }

    else{
        self.textFromCall.text = @"Invalid Phone number.";
    }
}

-(void)connectingStatement{
    self.textFromCall.text = @"Connecting...";
}


-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) UITextField *dialTextField;
@property (weak,nonatomic) UIButton *dialButton;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *textFromCall;

-(void) mainCall;
-(void) connectingStatement;
-(void) setString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

Now here is the Second Class: (PhoneCompany)

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PhoneCompany : NSObject

-(void) printPrompt;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "PhoneCompany.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation PhoneCompany

-(void) printPrompt{

    ViewController *mainView = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    mainView.dialTextField.text = @"Test";

}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you create dialTextField?

Comment: Make sure the object you are sending the message to actually exists. Make sure it is not nil. Use a breakpoint.

Comment: I created dialTextField in ViewController.m

Comment: Also, what do you mean by make sure it isn't nil and use a breakpoint?

Comment: No offense intended, but it sounds like you are in a little over your head. I recommend checking out the Stanford iOS online courses. They are free.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you are attempting to accomplish in the printPrompt method in the PhoneCompany class.

Comment: Yes... this was just to practice a little bit. I just really wanted to know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is and what actually happens. Is the `mainCall` method called? Is the `if` statement true?  Is the timer started? Is the `printPrompt` method called? Why does the `printPrompt` method create a view controller and then do nothing with it?

Comment: mainCall is called when the dialButton is clicked(in the viewDidLoad) the If Statement is true if user enters 1234567 in the text field and then clicks the dialButton. My Problem is in mainCall, the [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target:phoneCompany selector:@selector(printPrompt)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  does not let the printPrompt be called.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line that creates the timer. Do you reach the breakpoint? Set a breakpoint in `printPrompt`. Is it reached?

Comment: Made the breakpoint... I don't know how to check if i reached it. when i ran the code, a green line appeared on the breakpoint. But the Dialing and Connecting statement executed

Comment: Seriously, check this out https://itunes.stanford.edu. You need to know the basics before you can even understand the answers you'll get on this site.

Comment: I agree with Chris. You don't have enough understanding to be trying this yet. You have some profound misconceptions that are beyond the scope of a forum post to resolve. Get a book on beginning Objective-C programming and study it before trying to write your own programs. You're trying to run before you can even sit up.

Comment: Just before the call, NSLog the pointer you're basing the call on.  Odds are it's null.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to printPrompt is fine. The problem is that you are creating a new ViewContoller in the function. The one you created in printPrompt is not the same one where you call that function. I means setString: won't replace the text of textFromCall textfield. Somehow you need to pass ViewController to PhoneCompany as a delegate and call the setString: from it.

Edited:

Try this -

In PhoneCompany.h

```
@class PhoneCompany;

@protocol PhoneCompanyDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)phoneCompany:(PhoneCompany *)phoneCompay
          setString:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface PhoneCompany : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign)id<PhoneCompanyDelegate>delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<PhoneCompanyDelegate>)delegate;
- (void) printPrompt;

@end
```

In PhoneCompay.m

```
@implementation PhoneCompany

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<PhoneCompanyDelegate>)delegate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = delegate;
    }

    return self;
}


-(void) printPrompt
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(phoneCompany:setString:)])
    {
        [self.delegate phoneCompany:self
                          setString:@"Test"];
    }
}

@end
```

When you create the PhonCompany Object in prinPrompt

```
PhoneCompany *phoneCompay = [[PhoneCompany alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

In your ViewController.h

```
#import "PhoneCompany"

@interface ViewController:UIViewController<PhoneCompanyDelegate>
```

Comment: Isn't the ViewController *mainView i made part of the ViewController class?

Comment: It's a same class, NOT same object.

Comment: So what do I need to do then?

Comment: I just changed it so instead of setString: it just changes the text directly.. will that work?

Comment: Do you want me to code for you? If you want I can do that.

Comment: Just asking what I need to do... If you can give me some exact code that would be great!

Comment: I just edited my answer. forgot to add - (id)initWithDelegate:(id<PhoneCompanyDelegate>)delegate; to header file.

Comment: This conditional is completely unnecessary,  `if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(phoneCompany:setString:)])`

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying... It's just the fact that I haven't learned what you're saying... so before I try doing this I'm gonna go and learn more, but it seems like what you said worked, and thanks for helping anyways! @HMHero

Comment: Are there any websites/books that you can recommend to learn IOS Programming and Objective-C? @HMHero

Comment: @stackoverflowuser01 Sorry, English is not my first language =). Just get any 2-3 iOS development books for beginner. They will explain pretty much same thing but you will see the pattern and slightly different aspects of achieving same stuff. Apple Documents are also your best references. I also love http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials website.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! And your english is fine, it's just I don't even know what a delegate is, so it's just that I don't know the concept yet. @HMHero

Comment: I also managed to figure it out with a quite simple solution. @HMHero

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, all I had to do was declare the textFromCall as a static UILabel *textFromCall, and then declare a method to edit the text. Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: this breaks encapsulation and memory management. a really bad idea.